# java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found when connecting vault server from spring server

Tags: java, spring, ssl, openssl, hashicorp-vault

I have vault consul and server with TLS enabled and also the Spring app server which connects with vault for reading secrets, However when VaultPropertySource bean is created it tries to connect my vault server "https://localhost:8200/v1/secret/myapp" and somehow it get fail with Exception "java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found when connecting vault server from spring server"

Please note I have generated self signed certificate from the console:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:8200 -tls1 -servername localhost | openssl x509 -text -noout

SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert protocol version:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple
.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1145:SSL alert number 70
4207:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:/BuildRo
ot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64/src/ssl/s3_pkt.
c:566:
unable to load certificate
4208:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:/BuildRoot/Library/C
aches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64/src/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:64
8:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

Comment: Please post the output of `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1 -servername <hostname> | openssl x509 -text -noout`. Do so by adding it to your question by clicking *Edit* (and don't post it as a comment). Otherwise, there's not enough information to help troubleshoot it.

Comment: Have you specified "localhost" as the Subject of your self-signed cert?
If so, have you tried change it for the machine IP address?

Comment: @Hitesh - You need a modern version of OpenSSL. OpenSSL 0.9.8 is End Of Life and too old to be useful. The error above is due to `x509` subcommand.  If you omit it, then you will see the original error. Omit by issuing `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1 -servername <hostname>` (without the pipe).

Comment: Or if Java 7+ `keytool -printcert -sslserver localhost:8200` (use full path `..jre../bin/keytool` if not in your shell's PATH)

Comment: @Hitesh – please add that certificate to a keystore and configure the keystore to be used by your Vault client.